# c# wpf, trying to load data into a specific forms datagrid from a static method

Tags: c#, wpf, static

I am trying to load from a static method some data into my mainwindow-s datagrid (adding columns), I am trying to achieve this without creating a new instance of the window. I have hacked together a way to get around the static limitations but it fails with a error

```
   public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
        {
            static MainWindow mainWindow;
            public MainWindow()
            {

            InitializeComponent();
            ArgumentLoader();
            SqliteDatabase.check_for_database();
            SqliteDatabase.load_database();
            ColumnLoader("alias");

        }

    public static void ColumnLoader(string alias)
    { 
        DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        textColumn.Header = "X";
        textColumn.Binding = new Binding("X");
        mainWindow.dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
    }
```

**Exception**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

if I rename

```
mainWindow.dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
```

to

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
```

and make the method non-static it works. Am I missing something or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: I don't see you setting `mainWindow` to anything. Try adding `mainWindow = this;` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `mainWindow` to the object instance. You can do so in the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    mainWindow = this;

    InitializeComponent();
    ArgumentLoader();
    SqliteDatabase.check_for_database();
    SqliteDatabase.load_database();
    ColumnLoader("alias");
}
```